# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: The status code returned from the server is 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I am using windows application in .net and that application is internally calling one aspx page which have link button . When I tried to click on link button I got this error and also for your help Link button is just fetching data from database and showing in grid . Please help!

May be this question is duplicate but I didn't see any help after checked answers.

I am unable to get why this error is coming as I do have some other link button which is working fine.

This error I am getting only in windows app as when I am running aspx page in browser I am not getting this error ! Please help on this.

```
        <asp:LinkButton ID="linkViewLog" runat="server" Text="View Log Files" OnClientClick="javascript:ShowHideLogs();return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
        <div id="divLogs" style="visibility: hidden; display: none; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: 5px;">
            <telerik:RadButton ID="btnLogs" runat="server" Text="Refresh" OnClick="btnLogs_Click">
            </telerik:RadButton>
            <telerik:RadGrid ID="gridLogs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnDetailTableDataBind="gridLogs_DetailTableDataBind">
                <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="property">
                    <NoRecordsTemplate>
                        <div>
                            Loading Data...</div>
                    </NoRecordsTemplate>
                    <Columns>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="property" HeaderText="Property">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="lastupdate" HeaderText="Last Update">
                        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                    </Columns>
                       </MasterTableView>
            </telerik:RadGrid>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can we see some of your code, please?

Comment: I have added some part of code.

Comment: Probably the webview is in IE7 or similar (sort-of Compatibility Mode). Try adding an X-UA meta tag to put it in edge mode.
Also, attach a debugger to your server code and find the error, status code 500 means a server error trapped by the MS AJAX library and shown as a JS error.

Comment: I have resolved through debugger mode. Thanks for your help!